# CSS issue with responsive design

Tags: css

I recently added a mobile.css for my old format website to make it look little ok on hi-end mobile devices.

Almost all the pages has a Image at starting of the post with only property float:left.

```
.field-type-image img 
  {
    float: left;
  }
```

It looks ok on normal screen. I added a new css with @media screen and (max-width:1024) and adjusted few values to make it look OK on hand held devices. I wanted to make the image at that starting to each article to go little small , say almost half of actual resolution. hence I tried this.

```
.field-type-image img 
   {
    float: left;
    width: 46%;
    height: 32%;
  }
```

the width of the image seems to reduce on my ipad , mobile phone etc etc the way its supposed to be, but height is still the same as original one. So it looks very awful. However if on a normal browser from computer if I am shrinking the width of the screen then it does take the effect "height: 32%;" and looks ok. But on mobile browser,it looks like height: 32%; is not working. for example. http://www.rakeshmondal.info/IR-object-detection

How to reduce the height on CSS for an Image which works on mobile too? Since each every post on my site has image at starting with different resolutions so I cannot use a Fixed value for all piks to reduce the height Like width:300px; height:300px;.

I hope I am clear. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of good example and answer to this question, but before trying complex things, just try this small modification and see. Make the height auto, clear the cache and run corn and then check from your ipad.

```
.field-type-image img 
{
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for Commenting little late. Yes you were correct. I just made height:auto; just one line of code in the responsive design and it started working like a charm . Thanks Sanju ... Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;">` in the `<head>` tag of your html doc.

What that does is detects what device this is being used on and then if detected will follow the media queries.

Without that code the website would be responsive on a desktop but not on a mobile device.

Here is a helpful [article from smashing magazine.](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS to what's below.

```
.field-type-image img 
{
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%; /* keeps perspective for media queries */
}
```

If you want the image to "start" smaller for certain screen sizes, I'd recommend wrapping that `img` in a container that can manage that size.

For example, your stylesheet "could" resemble something like this (just an example, your HTML and CSS will be different, but the concept is the same):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .field-type-image
  {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
  }
  .field-type-image img
  {
    max-width: 100%; /* keeps perspective for media queries */
  }
}
```